# Rxdart combinelaststream function does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, rxdart, combinelatest

I am going to combine two stream. But it does not work. What is my mistake ?

**My build function is ;**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Observable.combineLatest2(
        getAllDBAccountsBloc.getAllDBAccountsStream,
        deleteDBAccountBloc.deleteDBAccountStream,
        (accountList, deleteAccountResultModel) {
          print("my account list : ${accountList == null}");
          return AccountsCombinerResult(
            deleteAccountResultBlocModel: deleteAccountResultModel,
            accountsList: accountList,
          );
        },
      ),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("hasData : ${snapshot.hasData}");
        if (snapshot.hasData) accountsCombinerResult = snapshot.data;
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        return _buildWidget;
      },
    );
  }
```

**Get All DB Accounts Stream Bloc is**

```
class GetAllDBAccountsBloc {
  final _getAllDBAccountsFetcher = PublishSubject<List<AccountDatabaseModel>>();

  Observable<List<AccountDatabaseModel>> get getAllDBAccountsStream => _getAllDBAccountsFetcher.stream;

  getAllDBAccounts() async {
    print("accounts getting");
    _getAllDBAccountsFetcher.sink.add(null);
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    _getAllDBAccountsFetcher.sink.add(await Repository.getAllDBAccounts());
    print("accounts get");
  }

  dispose() {
    _getAllDBAccountsFetcher.close();
  }
}

final getAllDBAccountsBloc = GetAllDBAccountsBloc();
```

**Delete  DB Account Bloc is**

```
class DeleteDBAccountBloc {
  final _deleteDBAccountFetcher = PublishSubject<DeleteAccountResultBlocModel>();

  Observable<DeleteAccountResultBlocModel> get deleteDBAccountStream => _deleteDBAccountFetcher.stream;

  deleteDBAccount(DeleteAccountRequestBlocModel requestModel) async {
    _deleteDBAccountFetcher.sink.add(DeleteAccountResultBlocModel());
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    _deleteDBAccountFetcher.sink.add(await Repository.deleteDBAccount(requestModel));
  }

  dispose() {
    _deleteDBAccountFetcher.close();
  }
}

final deleteDBAccountBloc = DeleteDBAccountBloc();
```

**Combiner result class is**

```
class AccountsCombinerResult {
  final DeleteAccountResultBlocModel deleteAccountResultBlocModel;
  final List<AccountDatabaseModel> accountsList;

  AccountsCombinerResult({
    @required this.accountsList,
    @required this.deleteAccountResultBlocModel,
  });
}
```

its mine Run log on android studio..

> I/flutter (28323): accounts getting
>
> I/flutter (28323): hasData : false
>
> I/flutter (28323): hasData : false
>
> I/flutter (28323): accounts get

The stream work but i did not get AccountsCombiner Result data.

This build method work but i don't want use it...

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getAllDBAccountsBloc.getAllDBAccountsStream,
      builder: (context, getDbAccountsSnapshot) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: deleteDBAccountBloc.deleteDBAccountStream,
          builder: (context, deleteDbAccountStreamSnapshot) {
            if (deleteDbAccountStreamSnapshot.hasData && getDbAccountsSnapshot.hasData) {
              print("qweqweq");
              accountsCombinerResult = AccountsCombinerResult(
                accountsList: getDbAccountsSnapshot.data,
                deleteAccountResultBlocModel: deleteDbAccountStreamSnapshot.data,
              );
            }
            if (getDbAccountsSnapshot.hasError) return Text(getDbAccountsSnapshot.error.toString());
            if (deleteDbAccountStreamSnapshot.hasError) return Text(deleteDbAccountStreamSnapshot.error.toString());
            return _buildWidget;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a new stream every time the `build` method is called. You need to keep the stream reference in the state.

```dart
StreamController<AccountsCombinerResult> _streamController = StreamController<AccountsCombinerResult>();

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamController.addStream(Observable.combineLatest2(
        getAllDBAccountsBloc.getAllDBAccountsStream,
        deleteDBAccountBloc.deleteDBAccountStream,
        (accountList, deleteAccountResultModel) {
          print("my account list : ${accountList == null}");
          return AccountsCombinerResult(
            deleteAccountResultBlocModel: deleteAccountResultModel,
            accountsList: accountList,
          );
        },
      ));
}

@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _streamController.close();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _streamController.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("hasData : ${snapshot.hasData}");
        if (snapshot.hasData) accountsCombinerResult = snapshot.data;
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        return _buildWidget;
      },
    );
}
```

To make this easier you could use the `StreamProvider` from the provider package.
https://pub.dev/packages/provider
https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html

It only build the stream once.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<AccountsCombinerResult>(
      initialData: null, // not sure if this works, you can try []
      create: () => Observable.combineLatest2(
        getAllDBAccountsBloc.getAllDBAccountsStream,
        deleteDBAccountBloc.deleteDBAccountStream,
        (accountList, deleteAccountResultModel) {
          print("my account list : ${accountList == null}");
          return AccountsCombinerResult(
            deleteAccountResultBlocModel: deleteAccountResultModel,
            accountsList: accountList,
          );
        },
      ),
      catchError: (context, error) => AccountsCombinerResult(
          deleteAccountResultBlocModel: null,
          accountsList: null,
          error: error,
      ), 
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
            final data = Provider.of<AccountsCombinerResult>(context);
            // maybe null check
            if (data.error != null) return Text(data.error.toString());
            accountsCombinerResult =data;
            return _buildWidget;
         },
      ),
    );
}
```

```dart
class AccountsCombinerResult {
  final DeleteAccountResultBlocModel deleteAccountResultBlocModel;
  final List<AccountDatabaseModel> accountsList;
  final dynamic error;

  AccountsCombinerResult({
    @required this.accountsList,
    @required this.deleteAccountResultBlocModel,
    this.error,
  });
}
```

The code is not tested so there may be typos or stuff that I missed, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: its doesn't work again... StreamProvider is not in flutter/material.dart package. StreamProvider is undefined object too. I tried first option but it's doesn't work again.

Comment: Does not work is not helpful, `StreamProvider` is from the provider package which you need to add to your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: i get same issue, print("my account list : ${accountList == null}"); this line doesn't triggered. On StreamProvider don't have create parameter. I guess you are working old version. My results are same.

Comment: I just noticed that your deleted stream probably has no items, `combineLatest` needs every source stream to emit before the resulting stream emits.

Comment: so need i sink data form deleteDBAccountStream block stream ? deleteDBAccountStream want to sink one time right ?

Comment: You may want to use `BehaviorSubject.seeded(null)` instead of `PublishSubject` + `add(null)`.

Comment: No I create a generic provider about that. It's solved now.